# How to load balance database servers with consistentency?

Tags: sql-server, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have 3 servers on Digital Ocean : Two web-servers and one database servers.
And I load-balanced on two web-servers. These web-servers are fine. But Memory and CPU usage on my database server is so high.

Can I add one database server and add one load-balancer between these DB servers synchronously and consistently?

Comment: can you please provide the specs of your db server? how much memory did you set on your db server?

Comment: here are my DB specs :4GB Ram , 2 vCPUs , 80GB SSD size

Comment: since this is a vm, can you add more ram on it? check what's causing the CPU, mem to peak.. check your max memory configuration on database. Most probably SQL is competing with OS on memory. And database is not like app servers that you can load-balance. database server scales upwards. Edit your question and add all the DB specs and OS version.